# I can't get the sections in my html program to go on one line when the media query is at 992px and above

Tags: html, css

I am making a program in html and I believe that I have the correct code but, what I want it to do is not working. The program is supposed to have 3 sections and when the browser window is 992px and above I want all of them to stay on the same row and as you make the browser wider and narrower I want the sections to become wider and narrower. In the tablet view (between 768px and 991px, inclusively), the first 2 sections should be in the first row and be of equal size. The 3rd section should be in the second row and take up the entire row by itself. In the mobile view (equal to or less than 767px), each section should take up the entire row.

Here is the link to my program,

http://codepen.io/Zaniac/pen/zBpKza

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
 }
 /**********BaseStyles***********/

 .section{
  border:5px solid blue;
  background-color: grey;
  padding:5px;
  margin:5px;
 }

 #lorem{
  float: right;
  top:0;
  border: 5px solid red;
  margin:-10px;
  padding: 3px;
  background-color: white;
 }
  .lg{
   
  }
  
  .sml{
   
  }

  .med{
   
  }
 /*Desktop device*/
 @media(min-width: 992){
  .lg{
   width:31%;
   float:top right;
  }
 }


 /*tablet devices*/
 @media(min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px){

 }

 /*mobile devices*/
 @media(max-width: 767){

 }

 



</style>
```

```html
<h1 id="title" align="center">Our Menu</h1>
<div class="section lg sml med" id="sec1">
<p id="lorem" >Spider Eye Stew</p>
<p class="lorem">    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum hendrerit quis magna quis dictum. Morbi et euismod est, sit amet placerat nulla. Praesent scelerisque metus eu turpis lacinia tempor. Aenean in vulputate orci. Donec ipsum orci, congue a fringilla at, blandit non eros. Vestibulum ac nunc suscipit, mattis sem ut, auctor erat. Maecenas vestibulum dui tortor, quis ornare odio imperdiet a. Sed nunc lacus, sollicitudin eu nulla maximus, condimentum ullamcorper libero. Donec quis lacus ultrices, accumsan purus sed, ornare arcu. Sed suscipit vulputate iaculis.</p>
</div>
<div class="section lg med sml" id="sec2">
<p class="lorem">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum hendrerit quis magna quis dictum. Morbi et euismod est, sit amet placerat nulla. Praesent scelerisque metus eu turpis lacinia tempor. Aenean in vulputate orci. Donec ipsum orci, congue a fringilla at, blandit non eros. Vestibulum ac nunc suscipit, mattis sem ut, auctor erat. Maecenas vestibulum dui tortor, quis ornare odio imperdiet a. Sed nunc lacus, sollicitudin eu nulla maximus, condimentum ullamcorper libero. Donec quis lacus ultrices, accumsan purus sed, ornare arcu. Sed suscipit vulputate iaculis.</p>
</div>
<div class="section lg med sml" id="sec3">
<p class="lorem">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum hendrerit quis magna quis dictum. Morbi et euismod est, sit amet placerat nulla. Praesent scelerisque metus eu turpis lacinia tempor. Aenean in vulputate orci. Donec ipsum orci, congue a fringilla at, blandit non eros. Vestibulum ac nunc suscipit, mattis sem ut, auctor erat. Maecenas vestibulum dui tortor, quis ornare odio imperdiet a. Sed nunc lacus, sollicitudin eu nulla maximus, condimentum ullamcorper libero. Donec quis lacus ultrices, accumsan purus sed, ornare arcu. Sed suscipit vulputate iaculis.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you have couple of mistakes:

1. float:top right doesn't exist, use float:right
2. In media querys write 992px (you forgot px)

That takes care of large screen.

On tablet screen set 2 elements width to 50% and 3rd one to 100%.
On mobile just set every element to 100%.

In any case don't forget to write px in media querys.

Comment: Mobile is also missing px. If you corrected that tell me what is not working.